# ApexCharts Crosshair for Y-axis Not Showing for Time series Line Graph

Tags: apexcharts

I want a horizontal crosshair line which I believe is on the y-axis. The x-axis crosshair is working just fine.

I am using the `show: Boolean` format as outlined in the documentation but nothing is rendering. Here is my actual code:

```js
    yaxis: {
      color: "#000000",
      axisBorder: { color: "#000000" },
      crosshairs: {
        show: true,
        position: "back",
        stroke: {
          color: "#000000"
        }
      },
```

Any ideas as to why the y-axis would not be showing up?

Comment: The code seems correct. Can you create a codepen to show the full code? Are you rendering a line chart or a horizontal bar chart?

Comment: I'm rendering a line chart @junedchhipa I don't think I can share the entirety of the code unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to have `yaxis.tooltip.enabled: true` to make the crosshair visible.